# how to run test by name with parameters in testng xml on maven command line

Tags: java, maven, testing, automation, testng

I have a testng.xml like below. I am trying to run test by names which are in testng.xml (myfirstcase or mysecondcase) by using maven command line.

command line:

```
mvn -Dtest=myfirstcase -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/Users/huseyintumer/IdeaProjects/experitestandroid/testng.xml test -f /Users/huseyintumer/IdeaProjects/experitestandroid/pom.xml
```

When i command line below, it works. But parameters in testng.xml does not pass.

```
mvn -Dtest=firstTest -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=/Users/huseyintumer/IdeaProjects/experitestandroid/testng.xml test -f /Users/huseyintumer/IdeaProjects/experitestandroid/pom.xml
```

Actually i dont want to run test by class name. I need to run test by test names in testng.xml with parameters.

testng.xml:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

<test name="myfirstcase">
    <classes>
        <class name="firstTest">
            <parameter name="udid" value="CQ300002LG" />
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="mysecondcase">

    <classes>
        <class name="firstTest">
            <parameter name="udid" value="BH90018AAX" />
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```